# Converter arquivo em Array de bytes

Tags: c#, asp.net, arquivo, webforms

Estou tentando converter um arquivo recebido no `FileUpload` (ferramenta do ASP.NET) para um *array* de *bytes* e depois o array para uma *string*.

Porém ao tentar usar o `Encoding` o Visual Studio acusa um erro dizendo que essa classe só aceita uma *string* para converter em *array* de *bytes*.

Segue o código:

```
if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
{
    try
    {
        if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg")
        {
            if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength < 102400)
            {
                System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] arrayImg = encoding.GetBytes(FileUploadControl.PostedFile);
                String img64Produto = Convert.ToBase64String(arrayImg);

            }
            else
                //StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file has to be less than 100 kb!";
                ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "msgErroLogin", "alert('O arquivo deve ser menor que 100KB!');", true);
        }
        else
            //StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Only JPEG files are accepted!";
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "msgErroLogin", "alert('Apenas .jpeg são suportados!');", true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        String msg = "O arquivo não pode ser carregado" + ex.Message;
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "msgErroLogin", "alert('O arquivo não pode ser carregado.');", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso que você tá tentando fazer não faz sentido, `Encoding.GetBytes()` é pra gerar o *array* de *bytes* **de uma string**.

O próprio `FileUpload` tem uma propriedade [**`FileBytes`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filebytes(v=vs.110).aspx) que contém os *bytes* do arquivo.

```
byte[] arrayImg = FileUploadControl.FileBytes;
```

Comment: Usei o FileUploadControl.FileBytes e funcionou obrigado!